# angular-cli - how to change the names of the generated css/js bundle files

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I am using angular-cli 1.0.0-beta.24. When I run `ng build --production`, is there a way to change the name of the generated *.bundle.css and *.bundle.js files?

The default names are: **main.[hash].bundle.js**, **styles.[hash].bundle.css**, **vendor.[hash].bundle.js** and **inline.[hash].bundle.js** and I would like to change these. Also this should reflect in automatic change of the generated css/script links in index.html.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

I think you can remove the hashes by providing --output-hashing none

Answer (score 1):

Sadly for now you can't do that.

There is a thread discussing this issue here:
https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/1656

According to the team they do not intend to allow customization of the Webpack configuration (Webpack is the tool that generates the transpiled files) anytime soon.

Changing the code in the files will update the [hash] in the **vendor** and **main** files but **inline** and **styles** will always have the same hash...

Someone in this thread suggested using the following [seed](https://github.com/qdouble/angular2webpack2-starter) which allows you to update the Webpack configuration of your Angular app (and seems to also support AOT and SSR) but I have not tested it to see if it actually works and it is not part of the angular-cli project.